# Create state variable only in iOS 16.1?

Tags: ios, swiftui, activitykit

Using global variable, this works:

```
@available(iOS 16.1, *)
var activity: Activity<RememberAttributes>?
```

If I want to try making it into a state variable, but I will get this error "'Activity' is only available in iOS 16.1 or newer".

Is it possible to create a state variable only when in iOS 16.1?

Comment: I solve the problem by putting this into a helper struct and make it @available(iOS 16.1, *). Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

No. You need to define your variables at compile-time. @available is evaluated at run time. The best you're going to be able to do is to make the variable an optional, and assign it a non-nil value from code wrapped in an @available. –